# angular material table with pagination: make rest call on click of next page

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

What is the best  way to handle next page click event when using mat-table with MatPaginator. I have created custom DataSource and have implemented connect() and disConnect() functions. Do I need to handle onClick of next page event explicitly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[The documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api)** :

```
@Output()                            Event emitted when the paginator changes
page: EventEmitter<PageEvent>        the page size or page index
```

Simply make your HTTP call and rebuild your datasource when you trigger this event.